# Function containing raster calculation returns error in R

Tags: r, r-raster

I am trying to create my own function with the raster calculation within it. But when I am calling the function it returns some error. The code is provided below

```
BT <- function(B_1, B_2){
  tir_10 <- raster::raster(B_1)
  tir_11 <- raster::raster(B_2)
  
  l_lambda_10 <- 3.3420*10^-4*tir_10 + 0.1
  l_lambda_11 <- 3.3420*10^-4*tir_11 + 0.1
  
  BT_10 <- (1321.0789/(log(774.8853/l_lambda_10 + 1)))
  BT_11 <- (1201.1442/(log(480.8883/l_lambda_11 + 1)))
  
  return(list(BT_10 = BT_10, BT_11 = BT_11))
}
```

Now I am trying to call the function using the following code

```
#Read the bands
library(raster)

a <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
set.seed(2)     
values(a) = runif(10000, min=27791, max=30878)

b <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
set.seed(2)     
values(b) = runif(10000, min=25686, max=28069)

BT(B_1 = a, B_2 = b)
```

But it returns following error

> Error in 3.342 * 10^-4 * tir_10 : hasValues(e2) is not TRUE

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines were wrong because `tir_10` and `tir_11` won't have values.

```
tir_10 <- raster::raster(B_1)
tir_11 <- raster::raster(B_2)
```

You could instead do:

```
BT <- function(tir_10, tir_11){ 
  l_lambda_10 <- 3.3420*10^-4*tir_10 + 0.1
  l_lambda_11 <- 3.3420*10^-4*tir_11 + 0.1
  
  BT_10 <- (1321.0789/(log(774.8853/l_lambda_10 + 1)))
  BT_11 <- (1201.1442/(log(480.8883/l_lambda_11 + 1)))
  stack(list(BT_10=BT_10, BT_11=BT_11))
}

library(raster)
a <- raster(ncols=100, nrows=100)
set.seed(2)     
values(a) = runif(10000, min=27791, max=30878)
b <- setValues(a, runif(10000, min=25686, max=28069))

x <- BT(a, b)
x    
#class      : RasterStack 
#dimensions : 100, 100, 10000, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 3.6, 1.8  (x, y)
#extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#names      :    BT_10,    BT_11 
#min values : 298.5254, 297.9016 
#max values : 305.6353, 304.4019
```

Comment: Actually, I have solved it by using `tir_10 <- raster::brick(B_1) tir_11 <- raster::brick(B_2)`. Is that OK?

Comment: Not really, because you are essentially making a copy for no reason

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `runif` using min and max coming from RasterLayers B_1 and B_2 in input inside the function, in this way:

```
BT <- function(B_1, B_2){
  tir_10 <- raster::raster(B_1)
  set.seed(2)     
  values(tir_10) = runif(10000, min=round(min(getValues(B_1)),0),max=round(max(getValues(B_1)),0))
  
  tir_11 <- raster::raster(B_2)
  set.seed(2)     
  values(tir_11) = runif(10000, min=round(min(getValues(B_2)),0), max=round(max(getValues(B_2)),0))
  
  l_lambda_10 <- 3.3420*10^-4*tir_10 + 0.1
  l_lambda_11 <- 3.3420*10^-4*tir_11 + 0.1
  
  BT_10 <- (1321.0789/(log(774.8853/l_lambda_10 + 1)))
  BT_11 <- (1201.1442/(log(480.8883/l_lambda_11 + 1)))
  
  return(list(BT_10 = BT_10, BT_11 = BT_11))
}
```

Comment: Within function it is not working but if you calculate it outside the function, it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I have the same error outside the function. Try to clean your environment using rm(list = ls()) and than try again the code outside the loop to double check it and let me know!

Comment: It is working outside the function. Like `l_lambda_10 <- 3.3420*10^-4*a + 0.1`. You have to load the `raster` package.

Comment: Ok, problem replicated. Maybe I have a solution, see answer updated and let me know ;-)

Comment: Actually, I will be using remote sensing images which will be having `ncol_b1, nrow_b1, runif_b1,min_b1, max_b1, ncol_b2, nrow_b2, runif_b2, min_b2, max_b2` these values within it. For creating a reproducible minimal example, I have created fake rasters. So, the function should be such that we need to provide the rasters only and it should able to calculate `BT`.

Comment: Ok, maybe the solution is there. Try to have a look to the updated answer

Comment: Why are you using `10000` within `runif`?

Comment: You were using it outside the function, but you can put the number you want of course

Comment: I think it should not be like that, it should take the values from raster. Here you are creating some fake values within the function for the raster not taking the true values from raster.

Comment: Ok, sorry to not been useful