# ifelse returning attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4' error in R

Tags: r, if-statement, r-raster

I am trying to set the values of E raster as 0.987 where b is over 0.5, otherwise use whatever was in E. For that, I am using the following code

```
a <- raster::raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
set.seed(2)
raster::values(a) = runif(10000, min=0.1, max=0.4)
b <- raster::raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
set.seed(2)
raster::values(b) = runif(10000, min=0.02, max=0.8)

c <- ((b - 0.2)/(0.5 - 0.2))^2
dE <- (1 - 0.9747)*(1 - c)*0.55*0.9896
E <- raster::raster(b)
E[] = ifelse(b[]>0.5, 0.989+dE, E[])
```

which returns me following error

> Error in rep(yes, length.out = len) :
> attempt to replicate an object of type 'S4'

How can I fix this error?

Comment: `E` appears to be an S4 object. That probably means you want to change values in a slot. Read `help("@")`.

Comment: @Roland Using `dE[]` like `E[] = ifelse(b[]>0.5, 0.989+dE[], E[])` removes the error. Is it the correct approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `terra::ifel` for this

```
library(terra)
set.seed(2)
a <- rast(ncols=10, nrows=10)
values(a) = runif(100, min=0.1, max=0.4)
b <- setValues(a, runif(100, min=0.02, max=0.8))    
c <- ((b - 0.2)/(0.5 - 0.2))^2    
dE <- (1 - 0.9747)*(1 - c) * 0.55 * 0.9896 + 0.989

E <- ifel(b>0.5, dE, b)
```

This is equivalent to

```
x <- mask(dE, b>0.5, maskvalues=0)
e <- cover(x, b)
```

See

```
plot(e, E); abline(0,1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now it is working without the error. Can you please answer [Function containing raster calculation returns error in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205666/function-containing-raster-calculation-returns-error-in-r)?